# Google API + PHP + Ajax Call - Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: php, ajax, api, cross-domain

I'm using the google API to access my calendar entries via OAuth.
Unfortunately I'm getting the following error (server is a local raspi):

> Failed to load https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&access_type=online&client_id=****-****.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fopenhabianpi.***.***%2Fsmarthome%2Fphp%2Fscripts%2Fscript.oauth2callback.php&state&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar.readonly&approval_prompt=auto: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://openhabianpi.***.***' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

My scripts:

**Ajax Request**

```
var termine = function (){
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/ajax/ajax.termine.php",
        data: {
            action: 'get_termine'
        },n
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

**ajax.termine.php**

```
require dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/config/client_secret.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
  $calendarId = 'primary';
  $optParams = array(
    'maxResults' => 10,
    'orderBy' => 'startTime',
    'singleEvents' => TRUE,
    'timeMin' => date('c'),
  );

  $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
  $results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
  if (count($results->getItems()) == 0) {
    print "No upcoming events found.\n";
  } else {
    print "Upcoming events:\n";
    foreach ($results->getItems() as $event) {
      $start = $event->start->dateTime;
      if (empty($start)) {
        $start = $event->start->date;
      }
      printf("%s (%s)\n", $event->getSummary(), $start);
        echo date('c');
    }
  }
} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'http://openhabianpi.***.***/smarthome/php/scripts/script.oauth2callback.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

**script.oauth2callback**

```
<?php
require_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/config/client_secret.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://openhabianpi.***.***/smarthome/php/scripts/script.oauth2callback.php');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect_uri = 'http://openhabianpi.***.***/smarthome/';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

I've tried the following, unfortunately without success:

1. > dataType: 'jsonp',
2. > header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
3. Setting in .htaccess or apache.conf

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You cannot call this using AJAX, you need to use browser redirect for the OAuth to work. See a similar thing I answered recently https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870488/cors-issue-making-ajax-request-from-react-app-node-server-redirect-to-google/50504098#50504098

Comment: I did a workaround with a service account. Thanks all.

Comment: Please post the details as an answer and accept the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script is working via ajax (you have to use a service account for this):

```
    <?php
    /**
    * Session aufbauen und user check
    */
    session_start();

    require dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/vendor/autoload.php'; //Google API via Composer

    $json_path = '***PATH to service account credential JSON***';

    $client = new Google_Client();

    $client->setAuthConfig($json_path);
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);

    $client->setApplicationName("***Your Appname***");

    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

    $calendarId = '***Your CAL ID***';
    $optParams = array(
       'maxResults' => 10,
        'orderBy' => 'startTime',
        'singleEvents' => TRUE,
        'timeMin' => date('c'),
    );

  $results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
  if (count($results->getItems()) == 0) {
    print "";
  } else {
    foreach ($results->getItems() as $event) {
      $start = $event->start->dateTime;
      if (empty($start)) {
        $start = $event->start->date;
      }

      $date = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($start));
      $time = date("G:i", strtotime($start));

      $today = date("d.m.Y");

      if ($date == $today){
        $array[] = array(
          "datum" => $date,
          "time" => $time,
          "termin" => $event->summary
        );
      }
    }
  }

  echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])){
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
    }
    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') 
    {
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST,OPTIONS");         
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
        exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: Access origin error mean: you requested URL not same as local requested URL
Or remote doesn't allow local requests.

Comment: This isn't working. Tried this at index.php, ajax and script.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use AJAX do do an OAuth authentication as the URL returned by `$client->createAuthUrl()` will show a login page.

You can still stay on the same page by following this steps:

- Open `ajax.termine.php` in a new tab.

`window.open('php/ajax/ajax.termine.php', '_blank');`

- Set the redirect uri to a blank page that only contains Javascript.
- Use this javascript to change the parent page URL.

`window.top.location.href = 'http://openhabianpi.***.***/smarthome/';`

Comment: Using a service account did the trick. Now I can use it with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to visit your google developer account and under API credentials add your web server address or IP address.

Visit [console.developers.google.com](https://console.developers.google.com)

Then select your project.
Then select credentials. Then select your API key. Then select Application restrictions then select HTTP referrers address and add your address.

[image]

Hope it solves your issue.